# Delphi Extract Text Between string List

Tags: delphi, extract

I need extract text from a string list ? this works very well so this extract only from a string. I need extract from a list in Tmemo.

Thanks

```
function ExtractTextBetween(const Input, Delim1, Delim2: string): string;
var
  aPos, bPos: Integer;
begin
  result := '';
  aPos := Pos(Delim1, Input);
  if aPos > 0 then begin
    bPos := PosEx(Delim2, Input, aPos + Length(Delim1));
    if bPos > 0 then begin
      result := Copy(Input, aPos + Length(Delim1), bPos - (aPos + Length(Delim1)));
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Show an example of list and result.

Comment: It's unclear what you want here. Do you want to extract the text for each line in a `TMemo`? So you want the result to be, what, a `TStringList` perhaps? A `TMemo` has a `Lines` property, so just iterate through those and use your existing function to extract for each one. Add them to a `TStringList`. Unless you want something different, then you'll need to explain more.

Comment: Apart from what @lurker says, if you want to extract from the full text of the memo, you can use the `TMemo.Lines.Text` property. If you want to access individual lines, use `TMemo.Lines` like an array.

Comment: Currently I can only extract a single string with this function, I want extract all the strings present in tmemo. example tmemo contains 100 lines this function extract only the fist line not  all lines

Comment: Have you considered what's been offered in the other comments so far? There's plenty there that should help you get started.

Comment: What does your input look like?

Comment: Do you need to know how to write a loop?

Comment: thank you  guys , i resolved   whit `TStringList` `result:=TStringList.Create;` and last line of code  `result.Add(Copy(Input, aPos + Length(Delim1), bPos - (aPos + Length(Delim1))))`

Comment: Make sure you `Free` that `TStringList` at some point when you're finished with it. That solution is a memory leak just begging to happen.

Answer (score -1):

not understand why not delimit properly, I need extract only email

**example string**

"email":"xxxx@xxxx.xom","cap":"00000",

```
memo3.Lines.AddStrings(ExtractText(memo2.Text,',"email":"','",')) ;
```

**result**
xxxx@xxxx.xom","cap

```
function ExtractText(const Str: string; const Delim1, Delim2: string): TStringList;
var
  c,pos1, pos2: integer;
begin
  result:=TStringList.Create;
  c:=1;
  pos1:=1;

  while pos1>0 do
  begin
    pos1 := PosEx(Delim1, Str,c);
    if pos1 > 0 then begin
      pos2 := PosEx(Delim2, Str, pos1+1);
    if pos2 > 0 then
      result.Add(Copy(Str, pos1 + length(delim1), pos2 - (length(delim2) + pos1)));
      c:=pos1+1;
     end;

  end;
```

Comment: It appears that you are trying to parse JSON manually. Definitely not a good idea. There are JSON libraries you can use, including the ones built-in to Delphi. Either way, I don't see how this answers your question.

Comment: Long story short, if you had just chosen to use a proper JSON library 9 hours ago when you asked your question, you would be way past this by now. JSON is not a line-break-based format, the entire JSON could be in a single line, or what you might expect to be 1 line might actually have 5 empty lines.